# Display Estimated delivery date in product Page

Tags: magento2, frontend, estimate, delivery-date

How to display estimated delivery date in product page when the user selects 
 country and zip code ?

Comment: When I have such a requirement with one of our client, we agreed to use a paid module https://store.plumrocket.com/estimated-delivery-date-magento2-extension.html

Comment: but i want to apply in my module...programmatically..

Comment: you can check this [magento 2 estimated delivery date](https://www.mageants.com/estimated-delivery-date-for-magento-2.html) module and test demo hopefully it solve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update this code :

> app/code/[NameSpace]/[ModuleName]/view/frontend/layout/catalog_product_view.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<body>
    <referenceContainer name="alert.urls">
        <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View" name="product.info.[ModuleName]" as="[ModuleName]" 
        after="-" template="[NameSpace]_[ModuleName]::product/view/temp.phtml"/>
    </referenceContainer>
</body>
```

> app/code/[NameSpace]/[ModuleName]/view/frontend/templates/product/view/temp.phtml

```
<?php
$product = $this->getProduct()
?>
<div>Estimated Delivery Date</div>
<div><?php // your code ?></div>

<div>Estimated Shipping Date</div>
<div><?php // your code ?></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can add block and .phtml in product view page and add your code as you want

Create catalog_product_view.xml in app/code/[NameSpace]/[ModuleName]/view/frontend/layout/

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<body>
    <referenceContainer name="alert.urls">
        <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View" name="product.info.[ModuleName]" as="[ModuleName]" 
        after="-" template="[NameSpace]_[ModuleName]::product/view/[fileName].phtml"/>
    </referenceContainer>
</body>
```

Create [fileName].phtml in app/code/[NameSpace]/[ModuleName]/view/frontend/templates/product/view

```
<?php
$product = $this->getProduct()
?>
<div>Estimated Delivery Date</div>
<div><?php // Your code ?></div>

<div>Estimated Shipping Date</div>
<div><?php // Your code ?></div>
```

Here you can add you logic to get Delivery and Shipping date and display according to Product

Comment: i'll try this way thank You :) Manoj Mondal

Answer (score 0):

Crate xml file on this path :

**app/code/[NameSpace]/[ModuleName]/view/frontend/layout/catalog_product_view.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<body>
    <referenceContainer name="alert.urls">
        <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View" name="product.info.[ModuleName]" as="[ModuleName]" 
        after="-" template="[NameSpace]_[ModuleName]::product/view/temp.phtml"/>
    </referenceContainer>
</body>
```

**app/code/[NameSpace]/[ModuleName]/view/frontend/templates/product/view/temp.phtml**

```
<?php
$product = $this->getProduct()
?>
<div>Estimated Delivery Date</div>
<div><?php // add your date function ?></div>

<div>Estimated Shipping Date</div>
<div><?php // add your date function ?></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

In **Magento 2.3** you can add following code in **/public_html/vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/templates/product/view/form.phtml**

```
<?php
$product = $this->getProduct()
?>
<div>Estimated Delivery Date</div>
<div><?php // Your code ?></div>

<div>Estimated Shipping Date</div>
<div><?php // Your code ?></div>
```

Here you can add you logic to get Delivery and Shipping date and display according to Product.

I DONT KNOW HOW TO CALL TODAY'S DATE IN MAGENTO THOUGH.

Answer (score 0):

**Magento 2.4 UPDATE:**

**app/code/[NameSpace]/[ModuleName]/view/frontend/layout/catalog_product_view.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<body>
    <referenceContainer name="alert.urls">
        <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View" name="product.info.[ModuleName]" as="[ModuleName]" 
        after="-" template="[NameSpace]_[ModuleName]::product/view/temp.phtml"/>
    </referenceContainer>
</body>
```

**app/code/[NameSpace]/[ModuleName]/view/frontend/templates/product/view/temp.phtml**

```
<?php
$product = $this->getProduct()
?>
<div>Estimated Delivery Date</div>
<div><?php // add your date function ?></div>

<div>Estimated Shipping Date</div>
<div><?php // add your date function ?></div>
```